# How to keep trailing 0s when round a number in python?

Tags: python, numpy, decimal, rounding

I wanted to keep two decimal places after the decimal and keep the trailing 0s for example. 17.7 I want it to be 17.70, or 22.00. So, I have a list of numbers I want to return the maximum and round so that it fits that format.

```py
list = [11, 12.3, 14, 200.33, 49.08, 207.2]

a = max(round(list), 2)
```

This is what I have done, but it still does not round all the points separately and keep the 2 decimal places. I am not tied to keeping round inside of max, I was just experimenting.

Comment: The zeros are always there (just like leading zeros). What you're looking for is how to format the string representation to show the trailing zeros.

Comment: One solution is to do the following:

    [math.floor(x * 100)/100 for x in list]

This will round everything to 2 decimal places for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, you can't. Unless you modify the underlying object, you cannot change its representation. What you might want is a string formatted to look like this.
Here are two approaches:

```
my_list = [11, 12.3, 14, 200.33, 49.08, 207.2]
['%.2f'%i for i in my_list]
```

output:

```
['11.00', '12.30', '14.00', '200.33', '49.08', '207.20']
```

f-strings (python >3.6):

```
[f'{i:.2f}' for i in my_list]
```

*NB. do **NOT** call a list "list", this is already a python builtin*

Comment: I know. I know just called it a list for the example i typed in here

Comment: @Hollywood Did it answer your question? you wanted strings?

Comment: Do I need the brackets surrounding [f'{i:.2f}' for i in my_list]

Comment: @Hollywood yes you do, it is called a list comprehension. If you problem is solved, please mark the answer as accepted.